# session not created (executionContextCreated has invalid 'context') from selenium on chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to parse through data available on a website and using selenium for the first time. After viewing multiple posts on Stack Overflow, I was able to figure out the PATH to error. Now when I run the script, command line shows(for Python27/Scripts) up and chrome opens up for a second or two (with a url = data) and then the script blows up. I am not that fluent with Python so I do not understand the error. I do not know why the Chrome browser opens a data in the url. Please provide your advice on this matter.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jose\Desktop\Programming\aspxscraping.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"15736.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448(52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: Can someone please provide assistance with this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running an old version of chromedriver (2.15). The latest is 2.25. 2.24 and 2.25 should work with your version of Chrome (54). Try [updating your chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/) and run it again.